# Generic class for enumerations - casting issue

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I want to write a generic class that accepts enumerations. Since this class is intended to implement some interfaces, the main aim is to be able to treat enumerations as other objects implementing those interfaces(e.g. for list extensions, etc). Hence, for a sample enum

```
public enum QEnum : int
{
    xlNoValue = 0,
    xlSomeValue = 1
}

public static class QEnumExtensions
{
    public static string toString(this QEnum xThis)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static QEnum toEnum(this string xThis)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to declare a generic class such as

```
public class QEnumHolder<T>  where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    private T mxVal = default(T);

    public QEnumHolder()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public QEnumHolder(T xVal) 
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new NotSupportedException();
        mxVal = xVal;
    }

    static public implicit operator QEnumHolder<T>(T xVal)
    {
        return new QEnumHolder<T>(xVal);
    }

    static public implicit operator T(QEnumHolder<T> xVal)
    {
        return (T)xVal.mxVal;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        if (mxVal is QEnum) return ((QEnum)Convert.ToInt32(mxVal)).toString();     
        ...
     }

    public void fromString(string xString)
    {
        if (mxVal is QEnum)
            mxVal = (???)xString.toEnum();       // problem
    }
}
```

All of the enumerations that we use implement

- toString() function which returns a "nice" string that can go into comboBoxes, etc
- conversion of string to enumeration, as above

hence the structure of toString/toEnum is pretty much given. The problem is with the last code line marked "problem". I have no idea how to tell the compiler that in this branch, the return type of `toEnum()` and `T` will be the same.

I tried to circumvent the problem by declaring `mxVal` as `int` and using `Convert.ToInt32` everywhere. However, then I run into problem in the `operator T` where the compiler has objections against converting `int` to a `T` (the compiler can't know that `T` will be enum, hence I can't use none of the "int to enum conversion" discussions here on SO).

Comment: As a general rule C# uses camel-case and for `ToString()` you should override.

Comment: @Bauss: I know, I just don't like it. The same with Equals(), etc - if you don't override it, you get an implementation you don't care for and nobody notifies you.

Comment: There are many problems with this design. If your class contains code like `is QEnum` and `(QEnum)something)`, i.e. a **concrete** types, then it's **not** a generic class. Also, you cannot have a multiple `ToEnum(string)` extension methods that differ only by the return type.

Comment: @Ivan: yes its not generic, but do you have a better idea given the fact that generics cannot be restricted to enums? As for the second point, an enumeration `QCountry` will have `toCountry(this string ..)`

Comment: The lack of `enum` constraints is unrelated. Btw, you don't have to check that in every constructor - just create a **static** constructor and put the code `if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)...` there. The problem is the need of all those `if`s. Are you really planning to wrote all these extensions methods for every your enum and **also** put a corresponding `if` in your holder class `toString` and `fromString` methods?

Comment: @IvanStoev: The extensions are already written. Yes, that is my intention. I will be glad for any better solution to this, right ... thanks for the static ctor.

Comment: See my answer. If the extensions methods are defined in different static classes, this can be provided to the static constructor via custom attribute or naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better design would be to use some naming convention, put all your enum extension methods in one and the same static class, and bind these functions inside your holder class **static** constructor. Something like this:

```
public static partial class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static MyEnumHolder<T> ToHolder<T>(this T source)
        where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        return new MyEnumHolder<T>(source);
    }
}

public class MyEnumHolder<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    static readonly Func<T, string> toStringFunc;
    static readonly Func<string, T> toEnumFunc;
    static MyEnumHolder()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new NotSupportedException();
        // Use your naming conventions
        var name = typeof(T).Name;
        toStringFunc = (Func<T, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>),
            typeof(MyEnumExtensions).GetMethod("toString", new[] { typeof(T) }));
        toEnumFunc = (Func<string, T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, T>),
            typeof(MyEnumExtensions).GetMethod("to" + name, new[] { typeof(string) }));
    }

    private T value;
    public MyEnumHolder() { value = default(T); }
    public MyEnumHolder(T value) { this.value = value; }
    static public implicit operator MyEnumHolder<T>(T x) { return new MyEnumHolder<T>(x); }
    static public implicit operator T(MyEnumHolder<T> x) { return x.value; }
    public string toString()
    {
        return toStringFunc(value);
    }
    public void fromString(string xString)
    {
        value = toEnumFunc(xString);
    }
}
```

Sample enum definitions (could be in separate files, but must be inside the same project):

```
public enum MyEnumA { A1, A2, A3 }
partial class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static string toString(this MyEnumA x)
    {
        //...
        return x.ToString();
    }
    public static MyEnumA toMyEnumA(this string x)
    {
        //...
        return (MyEnumA)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumA), x);
    }
}
```

and

```
public enum MyEnumB { B1, B2, B3 }
partial class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static string toString(this MyEnumB x)
    {
        //...
        return x.ToString();
    }
    public static MyEnumB toMyEnumB(this string x)
    {
        //...
        return (MyEnumB)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumB), x);
    }
}
```

test:

```
var a = MyEnumA.A1.ToHolder();
var sA = a.toString();
a.fromString("A2");
var b = MyEnumB.B2.ToHolder();
var sB = b.toString();
b.fromString("B1");
```

Comment: Ivan, thank you much, your code is much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
mxVal = (T)(object)xString.toEnum();
```

Comment: Like I said .. "if the solution is trivial". Seems to work, I will wait an hour for a potential discussion, and then accept this. Many, many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! I had this problem before when I was dealing with generics - took some time to figure it out